# Get percent result from database poll choices

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, count, percentage

I made a simple survey for my website with questions having 3-5 or more choices (radio buttons or check boxes).

In php, I get the number who chose a certain choice through the code:

```
  $query = "select count(distinct id) from survey_ans where question='q13' and answer='a3';";
  $res = mysql_query($query, $connection);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

this is for question 13 (q13), and the third choice (a3).

What I need is to know how can I count the numbers of any given answers for a question (e.g. q13: a1 +a2 + a3 + a4), the could be like 1600 who chose all the answers altogether, and instead of the above code to get the number of answers for each choice, I get the percentage from the total answers of the whole question.

So it shows me that 15% of the people who answered question 13 chose answer 3, while answer 4 got 55%.. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can get the counts using aggregation:

```
select answer, count(id)
from survey_ans
where question = 'q13'
group by answer;
```

I am guessing that the `count(distinct)` really isn't necessary.  `count()` is better to use when you can.

To get the total, join that in:

```
select sa.answer, count(sa.id), tot.total
from survey_ans sa cross join
     (select count(*) as total from survey_ans where question = 'q13') as tot
where question = 'q13'
group by sa.answer;
```

You can get the percentage with something like:

```
select sa.answer, 100.0*count(sa.id)/tot.total as percentage
from survey_ans sa cross join
     (select count(*) as total from survey_ans where question = 'q13') as tot
where question = 'q13'
group by sa.answer;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  The first two aggregations work fine, however the last one of the percentage gives an error: ( #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by sa.answer' at line 1 )

Comment: @Mike . . . That's what I get for leaving in an extra semicolon.  Fixed. now.